# How to stop redirection from server side

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, http-headers

I am using an AJAX call to access some resource from external server. But the server redirects me to another location and do not return anything. I want to get the the url of that location....

Exampl on JS Fiddle....http://jsfiddle.net/5KtVE/2/

Comment: put the code in 1 IFRAME, catch the "window.onload" event, then get the "document.location" of the IFRAME. not a real good solution but may work!

Comment: How I can capture the onload event of IFRAME [http://jsfiddle.net/5KtVE/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/5KtVE/2/)

Comment: IFRAME is just like 'window' object, take a look over this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: No.. It is returning the location of current window..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is a crossdomain request you have to set the `dataType` option to `jsonp`, this should work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/mahernazeer/picture', 
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(imageUrl) {
        console.log(imageUrl);    // https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/274173_100002201391414_6210108_q.jpg
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5KtVE/3/